# GlassFish: email log handler

Tags: java, logging, glassfish, jakarta-mail

We need to send mail from a log handler in GlassFish v3.1.2.2.

We've tried to use smtphandler-0.6 and -0.7 with limited success. We install the jarfile to domain/lib/ext, and configure smtphandler's properties in domain/config/logging.properties. We've tried two ways of satisfying smtphandler's reliance on mail imports: 1) Editing its manifest classpath to point to ../../../../modules/javax.mail.jar, and 2) Putting javax.mail.jar in domain/lib/ext alongside the smtphandler jar. (We prefer the former approach so that the same javamail classes are used throughout the system. But it seems to make no difference, no worky either way.)

With either of these arrangements the behavior is the same:

- The handler loads ok as shown by the JVM's verbose:class output.
- Sometimes it sends mail for errors and warnings that occur during domain startup (like the expired certificate). Other times it fails as described below before ever sending mail.
- It always fails once we've deployed our application and logged some application errors. We can tell that the handler is invoked - that's evidenced by the debugger and some primitive System.out "logging".

The root problem is a NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.[init](Session, URLName). The failure to find the c'tor means the transport object can't be created; that eventually manifests as a NoSuchProtocolException.

We can see that the SMTPTransport class is loaded and that it has the requested c'tor. Our best theory is that class loading is somehow involved, but we've not been able to figure out exactly how. (Yet. We're working that angle now.)

Questions:

- Are we deploying the handler to the correct location (domain/lib/ext) ?
- Why does it (sometimes) send mail during an (empty, no apps) domain startup, but fail for logs emitted by our application? That's a race condition, surely, but what are those threads doing that occasionally works for a bit then reliably fails?
- Are we right to think that all these indications together imply a class loading issue?

We've reproduced these symptoms on GlassFish versions 3.1.2.2 and 4, with JavaMail 1.4.4 and 1.5.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug was reported for this [NoSuchMethodException when attempting to install log handler in GlassFish server](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/20800).  This issue was raised with the JavaMail team under [Bug K6668 | GH144 - skip unusable Store and Transport classes](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/issues/144) which is [fixed in JavaMail 1.5.3](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/commit/ef1b56b5ef81e9a3cc133563b24e91aaf9f92872).  Upgrading the JavaMail module in glassfish and all other copies deployed should correct the issue.  It is also helpful to start glassfish with "glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain -v" so you can see all bootstrapping messages.

> •Are we deploying the handler to the correct location (domain/lib/ext)

Yes.  You can deploy to domain/lib/ext but you have to include JavaMail 1.5.3 so you find the correct transport service.  Otherwise, you can deploy the jar to the modules dir and add the [HK2 metadata](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/commit/1e38e09637cf94fbc64926b7cf6f5a508f08f0b3) to make the smtphandler look like a service. This can be done by including new jar or modifying the existing smtphandler jar.

For GlassFish 3, the file `META-INF/inhabitants/default` must be added containing the following:

```
class=smtphandler.SMTPHandler,index=java.util.logging.Handler
```

For GlassFish 4, the file `META-INF/hk2-locator/default` must be added containing the following:

```
[smtphandler.SMTPHandler]
contract={java.util.logging.Handler}
scope=javax.inject.Singleton
```

The jar then has to be placed in the `glassfish/modules` folder along with upgrading javax.mail.jar.

Another option is to subclass smtphandler to look like a HK2 log handler service and add a preDestroy method to trigger the email on shutdown.  This is described in the Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Administration Guide Part I section 7 titled [Adding a Custom Logging Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#ghmen).

Under GlassFish 4 there are [two different ways](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/19323) to locate a handler in the logging.properties.  Handlers placed in `domain/lib/ext` use the standard `handlers` key in the properties file.  Handlers placed in the `glassfish/modules` as a HK2 Service are loaded using the `handlerServices`  key in the properties file.

```
#GF3 ext/endorsed or OSGI.  GF4 ext/endorsed only.
handlers=smtphandler.SMTPHandler

#GF4 OSGI only, 'handlerServices' should not contain any whitespace characters between handlers.
handlerServices=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler,smtphandler.SMTPHandler
```

> •Why does it (sometimes) send mail during an (empty, no apps) domain startup, but fail for logs emitted by our application? That's a race condition, surely, but what are those threads doing that occasionally works for a bit then reliably fails?

Difference in [context class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader--) between messages logged by GF vs your web app. The CCL is used in JavaMail to locate the transport.  Patching the 'sendBuffer' method should fix the behavior:

```
@Override
protected void sendBuffer() {
    final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader ccl = null;
    try {
        ccl = thread.getContextClassLoader();
        thread.setContextClassLoader(
                javax.mail.Transport.class.getClassLoader());
    } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
    }
    try {
        super.sendBuffer();
    } finally {
        try {
            thread.getContextClassLoader();
            thread.setContextClassLoader(ccl);
        } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

> •Are we right to think that all these indications together imply a class loading issue?

Yes.  The only way to really make this work right is to subclass or patch the smtphandler to look like an HK2 component and modify the CCL.

> We need to send mail from a log handler in GlassFish v3.1.2.2.
>   We've tried to use smtphandler-0.6 and -0.7 with limited success.

**Disclaimer:** I'm a content developer for [MailHandler](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/CHANGES.txt) included with JavaMail project.

An alternative to the smtphandler is the [com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/package-summary.html) included with the JavaMail reference implementation.

Under GlassFish 4 you have to have `glassfish/modules/javax.mail.jar` that is [JavaMail 1.5.3 or newer](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  An updated version can be downloaded from the [JavaMail API homepage](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) and can be used to replace the version bundled with GlassFish.

Next you have to modify the `logging.properties` for the domain.  Here is a sample configuration you can include to get you started.

```
#Ensure no whitespace between handler class names.
handlerServices=com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler,com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler    
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.subject=com.sun.mail.util.logging.CollectorFormatter
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.CollectorFormatter.format=GlassFish 4.x:{0}{1}{2}{4,choice,-1#|0#|0<... {4,number,integer} more}
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter.format=[%4$-7.7s] %7$#.140s
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.level=WARNING
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.filter=com.sun.mail.util.logging.DurationFilter
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.pushLevel=WARNING
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.host=some-smtp-host
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.user=some-user
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.authenticator=some-password
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.from=app@server.com
#com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.sender=team@list.com
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.to=devs@bugfixers.com
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.verify=resolve
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.quitwait=false
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtps.quitwait=false
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=45000
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtps.connectiontimeout=45000
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtp.timeout=45000
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.mail.smtps.timeout=45000
```

For GlassFish 3 you have to install JavaMail (javax.mail.jar) under the `domain/lib/ext` or `glassfish/lib/endorsed` and test that this doesn't break any of your applications.  This classloader configuration also works under GlassFish 4 and allows combining the MailHandler with [MemoryHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html) which can emulate the behavior of the smtphandler.

Next you have to modify the `logging.properties` for the domain.  You can use the same sample as the GlassFish 4 except that you have to use the standard `handlers` tag instead of the `handlerServices`.

```
handlers=java.util.logging.MemoryHandler
java.util.logging.MemoryHandler.target=com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler
java.util.logging.MemoryHandler.size=512
java.util.logging.MemoryHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.MemoryHandler.push=WARNING
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.capacity=512
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.level=INFO
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.pushLevel=WARNING
com.sun.mail.util.logging.MailHandler.filter=com.sun.mail.util.logging.DurationFilter
com.sun.mail.util.logging.DurationFilter.records=512
com.sun.mail.util.logging.DurationFilter.duration=5*60*1000
```